# How to adjust value of a "User define String" into a Array in PHP

Tags: php, arrays

I am a newbie in PHP & sorry if it's a basic question.
I have a variable which contains string values

Its User define means the number of values in string may vary (user could choose up to Z)

```
$raw_data= "A=400 B=500 C=300";
```

Now I want these values in a array which should be like:

```
$data = array (array('A', 400),array('B', 500),array('C', 300));
```

any help ???
Thanks in Advance.

Comment: let the code golf begin

Comment: map explode space return explode=

Comment: You should also provide what you have tried and where you are stuck.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
$data = [];
foreach (explode(" ", $raw_data) as $part) $data[] = explode("=", $part);
```

This will give you the `$data` you want in your code above. Alternatively you can use [array_map](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-map.php).

```
$data = array_map(function($d) {
    return explode("=", $d);
}, explode(" ", $raw_data));
```

Comment: @Rawat_ji will you use the numbers(400,500,...) to further process, like minus or plus?

Comment: @SuperCoolHandsomeGelBoy Numeric operations will automatically convert the number into integral form (this is called type juggling), but op can always cast (int) on the variable like so: `$num = (int)$data[0][1];`

Answer (score 0):

The `explode()` function breaks a string into an `array`.
syntax `explode(separator,string,limit)// limit is optional`

```
 <?php
    $raw_data= "A=400 B=500 C=300";
    $data = explode(' ',$raw_data);
    foreach($data as $value){
    $new[] = explode("=", $value);
    }
    echo "<pre>";print_r($new);
```

It will give you result as

```
    Array
    (
        [0] => Array
            (
                [0] => A
                [1] => 400
            )

        [1] => Array
            (
                [0] => B
                [1] => 500
            )

        [2] => Array
            (
                [0] => C
                [1] => 300
            )

    )
```